# doesn't displays the ip address of the system

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

the following code runs successfully but i couldn't get the ip address of the system.

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher mos=new ManagementObjectSearcher("select IPAddress,IPEnabled from win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled=true");
 ManagementObjectCollection moc=mos.Get();
 foreach(ManagementObject mo in moc)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Variable = {0},Value = {1}  ",
         mo["IPAddress"],mo["IPEnabled"]);
 }
```

the above code results as

```
  " Variable = System.String[]  ,  Value = True"
```

can you tell me how to get my system's ip address...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your original code do the following

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos=new ManagementObjectSearcher("select IPAddress,IPEnabled from win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled=true");
 ManagementObjectCollection moc=mos.Get();
 foreach(ManagementObject mo in moc)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Variable = {0},Value = {1}  ",
         (string[])mo["IPAddress"],mo["IPEnabled"]);
 }
```

*if you debug the answer you will see that when you place the mouse outside on the **'('** here on this line **(string[])mo["IPAddress"],mo["IPEnabled"])** you will see IP Address and a Mac Address*

Comment: I am glad that I could quickly help you